# What's the most optimal query in PgSql to find the nearest neighbor in a huge dataset?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, postgis, knn, nearest-neighbor

I have a huge table (about 40 Millions rows) called nearest_spot representing lines (in the linestring format) and the closest spot they're to (there is about 1500 different spot, stored in another table). The nearest_spot table comes like this :

```
 data_id || spot_id || spot_name || link_geom
```

Where **data_id** the the primary key, **spot_id** is a foreign key to the primary key of the spot table, **spot_name** is the spot name (I know redundancy isn't good but I'm not allowed to modify the database) and **link_geom** is the line coordinates.

---

The database is in PostgreSQL 10.6, PostGIS 2.5, there is a gist index for the **link_geom** column, and a VACUUM ANALYZE has already been done on the nearest_spot table.

My goal is to find the nearest neighbor (in this table) to a point in a data record, as fast as possible.

I already know how to find the nearest neighbor, my problem is the time it takes to find it. I'm pretty new to PostgreSQL and PostGIS and I've been reading their documentations, going through a lot of topics about KNN optimizations, I've been searching for the most effective answer and yet I can't have a result under 5 minutes (and it goes up to 30min sometimes), even when only searching for one row . The different queries I've tried are as follows :

```
SELECT *
FROM( SELECT A.position, B.spot_id
      FROM data A, nearest_spot B
      WHERE A.id = 1
      AND ST_DWithin(A.position,B.link_geom,20)
      ORDER BY A.position <-> B.link_geom
      LIMIT 10;)
ORDER BY ST_Distance(A.position,B.link_geom)
LIMIT 1;

SELECT *
FROM( SELECT A.position, B.spot_id
      FROM data A, nearest_spot B
      WHERE A.id = 1
      AND ST_Buffer(A.position,20) && B.link_geom
      ORDER BY A.position <-> B.link_geom
      LIMIT 10;)
ORDER BY ST_Distance(A.position,B.link_geom)
LIMIT 1;

SELECT *
FROM( SELECT A.position, B.spot_id
      FROM data A, nearest_spot B
      WHERE A.id = 1
      AND ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(A.position,20), B.link_geom)
      ORDER BY A.position <-> B.link_geom
      LIMIT 10;)
ORDER BY ST_Distance(A.position,B.link_geom)
LIMIT 1;
```

The reason I ORDER BY with `<->` first, then with ST_Distance is that according to this [documentation](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html#index-based-knn) from PostGIS, `<->` is faster but less precise (for bounding boxes) while ST_Distance is more precise but slower.

I also used this [documentation](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html#index-only-queries) about Spatial Indexing, and this [one](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) about the `<->` operator, both from PostGIS also.

**EDIT:** I realized all my coordinates are stored as geometry (SRID 4326), so the ST_DWithin call, while having good syntax, was returning all rows not within 20 meters as a thought it would, but all rows within 20 degrees (of earth), so in fact my ST_DWithin wasn't making the result set any smaller, and it might be one of the biggest reason why it was taking so long, and the same goes for ST_Buffer. I'll try to cast all coordinates as geography (with `::geography`) before using them with meters and hopefully I'll see an improvement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the table had a huge amount of duplicates (each row was repeated about 1800 times) and the person who gave it to me didn't know about it at all. I don't have a problem with query time anymore after deleting duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Does in need to be done by the database? I think the fastest way is probably loading the 
1500 spots into a spatial index, such as KD-Tree, quadtree or R-Tree. Then iterate over the 40M points and search the nearest neighbor in the index.

Without much effort, you should be able to do 100,000 upto 500,000 NN-searches per second, so 40M NN-searches should take roughly 2 to 5 minutes.

Comment: PostGIS provides spatial indexing.

Comment: @inc42  Yes, the OP even wrote that they used PostGIS spatial indexing, but apparently it was to slow. I am not sure what your point is?

Comment: I am not sure what performance benefit you would imagine by using a different spatial index and data structure than what PostGIS offers. Why would that be faster than a well-tested and proven spatial database?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but PostGIS is a plugin/extension/... for PostgreSQL, which is a relational database. That means it comes with a lot of overhead for managing ACID behavior, query processing, table to in-memory object mapping, and most likely disk I/O. So instead of a well-tested and proven DBMS (with all the unnecessary DBMS overhead) I suggested some well-tested and proven in-memory spatial indexes. Why would that not be faster?

Comment: You'd be surprised I think.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but PostGIS uses internally a spatial index. Can you explain why using a spatial index directly (as I propose) should not be faster than using a spatial index via a wrapper with plenty of loigc in it, such as PostGIS? 
If you know something that I do not, it would be very helpful if you could share some facts or insight. Just giving opinions without explanations here is not not very helpful, so could you please explain how and why this should be possible?